# Is anyone has experienced compatibility issues with the "Asrock Z270 Extreme4" mainboard and with "Ubuntu 16.04.3"?

Tags: boot, 16.04, usb

I tried to install Ubuntu 16.04.3 LST on mainboard Asrock Z270 Extreme4. But I got an error like below:

[image]

I saw the posts of similar cases on this site and following them could not fix this problem.

I tried with more than three usb stick and even a dvd connected by SATA and none of them worked.

There's no problem with Windows 10 or Ubuntu 17.04.

Additionally the usb installer that I used on this PC works fine on other PCs except for another PC with Asrock Z270 Extreme4 mainboard which is exactly the same as mine!

I gave up and work with Ubuntu 17.04 for now, but I am really curious to see what kind of compatibility issues may exist.

Comment: There is no difference between 16.04.3 and 17.04 in installation. They are using the same kernel. It is very strange.

Comment: I've seen a couple of posts on the internet suggesting that the MB does not seem to like to boot from USB [http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-3213571/install-linux-asrock.html](http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-3213571/install-linux-asrock.html) or that the BIOS may need an update [https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2308445](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2308445)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. For your reference, the BIOS on the motherboard is confirmed to be the latest updated version on 6/13/2017.
(The 1st row of the table: http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/Z270%20Extreme4/index.asp#BIOS)

Comment: I am having the exact same problem with 20.04.  Did you ever resolve it?  My old MB died and I had to replace it with the Asrock 270.  I am starting to regret it.  I always buy ASUS but there was nothing available.  I have to use Windows (UGG) if I want my USB ports to work.